# Code obfuscation for accessing an array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, stl

I was going through a code that I found online, and found out that the code used to access an array of vectors is a little off-beat (read *obfuscated*).

The array `graph` and `visited` are declared as follows:

```
vector< int > graph[ MAXN + 1 ], graphT[ MAXN + 1 ], sorted;
bool visited[ MAXN + 1 ];
```

And further in the program, it is accessed as below:

```
if ( !visited[ graph[ S ][ i ] ] ) {         //--->>>???
            dfs1( graph[ S ][ i ] );
        }
```

Could someone please help me explain how is `visited [ graph[ S ][ i ] ]` correct syntax to access the `visited` array?  Also, is there any other simpler way to access it?

Note: `S` is just any random variable, with value, say `1`.  Actual link of the code is [here](https://github.com/VitSalis/SPOJ/blob/master/BOTTOM/bottom.cpp). I am talking about lines 9, 10, 27, 28 and 29.  Of course, the code compiles successfully and generates the required output.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`graph` is an array of `std::vector<int>` objects. `graph[S]` returns the `S`-th element of that array. It is of type `std::vector<int>&`. `std::vector` implements `operator[](size_t)`, so `graph[S][i]` returns the `i`-th member of the vector stored at position `S` in `graph`.

The type of `graph[S][i]` is `int&`, and can be implicitly converted to `size_t`. Passing `size_t` as an index into an array (`visited`) returns a reference to that element.

In other words: `graph` is a two-dimensional array of `int`s<sup>1)</sup>, that can be indexed using `[x][y]`. It returns a value that is used as an index into the `visited` array.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *It's odd, that the author decided to use different containers for the 2 dimensions (a classic array for the first, a `std::vector` for the second). Either one can be indexed using the indexing operator (`[]`), which does make this a bit confusing.

It could have been written as `std::vector< std::vector< int > > graph( MAXN + 1 );` for more consistency.*

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please elaborate a bit more on the second paragraph?  How did you understand the type is `const int&`?  And that `visited` will return a const reference?

Comment: Since `graph` is not a `const` object, `graph[S]` evaluates to a `std::vector<int>&`.

Comment: @RSahu: Do you happen to have a Standard reference that explains, how the return type of an array is deduced?

Comment: 5.2.1 Subscripting, para 1. *A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is an lvalue of type “T.”*

Comment: You can use `std::vector<int> & g0 = graph[S];` to verify that.

Answer (score 5):

This is not C++11, in the sense that no C++11 features are used, and nothing is obfuscated.

You can rewrite the code as follows, assuming that `graph` is non-const:

```
std::vector<int> & g0 = graph[S];
int & g1 = g0[i];
if (!visisted[g1])
  dfs1(g1);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please elaborate why you have written `std::vector<int> const & g0` and not just `std::vector<int> g0`?  How did you understand and what is the difference?

Comment: @user6490375 The difference is that the `operator[]` doesn't return a copy, it returns a reference (possibly const). You can certainly construct a copy from that reference, but that'd be horrible premature pessimization - you don't need these copies, and the compiler doesn't make such copies either.